# Restricting webscrape to id "group"

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have created a really basic webscraper in excel to try and pull information from a chemical dossier at:

https://echa.europa.eu/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/15460/7/1

code:

```
Public Sub GetContents()
    
'Start ECHA Search via XML HTTP Request
    
    Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    XMLReq.Open "Get", "https://echa.europa.eu/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/15460/7/1", False
    XMLReq.send
     
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText
    
'Retrieve Info
    Set Info = HTMLDoc.getElementById("SectionContent")
    
    
    Debug.Print Info.innerText

End Sub
```

So far this pulls all of the information of the page however looking at the page you can see that there are different subsections for: `Workers - Hazard via inhalation route`, `Workers - Hazard via dermal route`, `Workers - Hazard for the eyes` and so on. Ideally I would like to be able to restrict the information to these groups however all the information seems to be bundled under `SectionContent` and unlike other pages on echa the data isn't contained within groups.

Does anyone who understands ccs selectors for web scraping know if this can be done with the structure of this page? the only thing I can think of is if its possible to somehow say .innerText for all the information under element with id x until the next id however I have no idea how to do this nor am I sure if this is the best way.

If someone could comment that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Sub GetContents()
Dim Info As Variant
Dim MiMatriz As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim MySeparators As Variant

MySeparators = Array("Workers - Hazard via inhalation route", "Workers - Hazard via dermal route", "Workers - Hazard for the eyes", "Additional information - workers")


'Start ECHA Search via XML HTTP Request

Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

XMLReq.Open "Get", "https://echa.europa.eu/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/15460/7/1", False
XMLReq.send
 
HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText

'Retrieve Info
Set Info = HTMLDoc.getElementById("SectionContent")


For i = 0 To UBound(MySeparators) - 1 Step 1
    Range("A" & i + 1).Value = MySeparators(i) & Split(Split(Info.innerText, MySeparators(i))(1), MySeparators(i + 1))(0)
Next i

'clear variables
Set Info = Nothing
Set XMLReq = Nothing


End Sub
```

You can split the innertext according to your need, using those h3 texts as delimiters.

The output of this code is 3 cells, each one with 1 category.

[image]

Probably you still need to trim and clean more the output, but at least it's a starting point.