# restricting webscrape to id group (part 2)

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

This is a follow up question to: [Restricting webscrape to id "group"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68130051/restricting-webscrape-to-id-group)

Essentially I am trying to capture the information in: https://echa.europa.eu/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/15460/7/1 but restrict what is returned per section.

The previous answer works well to delimit the information per section using the phrase of each section, however unfortunately my previous question wasn't thorough enough. So far all the information is pulled into one cell whereas I wish to capture the information per row across 2 columns. The code below achieves this for all of the information:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetContents2()

    Sheets("Substance Dossier").Select
    
    Dim http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    Set http = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60: Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    With http
        .Open "GET", "https://echa.europa.eu/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/15460/7/1", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Dim nodeList As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection, i As Long, r As Long, Header As String, Data As String

    Set nodeList = html.querySelectorAll("#SectionContent h3,#SectionContent h4,#SectionContent h5,#SectionContent h6, #SectionContent  dt, #SectionContent dd")
 
    r = 1
 
    For i = 1 To nodeList.Length - 1
         
         Select Case nodeList.Item(i).tagName
            
            'Retrieves info with dt tag (Headers)
            Case "DT"
               Header = nodeList.Item(i).innerText
               r = r + 1
                ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 2) = Header
            
            'Retrieves info with dd tag (Data)
            Case "DD"
                Data = nodeList.Item(i).innerText
                ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 3) = Data
            
            'Inserts SubHeadings
            Case Else
                Header = vbNullString
                r = r + 1
                ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 2) = nodeList.Item(i).innerText
   
    Debug.Print Header, Data, nodeList.Item(i).innerText
   
        End Select
    Next
    
End Sub
```

I wish to modify this code so that the information is only pulled for a given section e.g. `Workers - Hazard via inhalation route` or `Workers - Hazard via dermal route` or `Workers - Hazard for the eyes` independently, whilst still ensuring the data is captured in separate rows. Whether this is achieved by delimiting as per the previous answer or via a different method I am not yet sure.

I'm thinking that I can somehow create a variable and set this to the output of the for loop and then delimit this but I am unsure how since I cant assign the variable outside of the loop.

As the desired output:

[image]

I wish to be able to specify either `Workers - Hazard via inhalation route`, `Workers - Hazard via dermal route`, `Workers - Hazard for the eyes` in the code ( I can assign this to a cell value) and independently have only the relevant info for this section returned.

Apologies for posting in two parts however I feel that with my previous mistake this is warranted. I will update with any progress made but if you have any answers on how to achieve this please let me know.

Comment: So, would Hazard for the eyes return just 3 rows?

Comment: Are you seeking solutions which can handle potential change in ordering of sections or assuming is fixed?

Comment: @QHarr Yeah exaclty for eyes it would return: `Local effects
Hazard assessment conclusion: low hazard (no threshold derived)`

Comment: @QHarr Hm I suppose I would be looking for an answer that can handle changes in case the website structure isnt exactly fixed e.g. a section was missing. That being said they sections should follow a relative order i.e. Workers - hazard via inhalation I think will always be first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sticking with similar logic to yours I would walk the DOM. Set your start node as the `H3` tag for your selected hazard. You can construct the element `ID` dynamically from the target text and use that as part of your css selector.

With this start node, walk the DOM, sibling to sibling (setting `node` as the `node.nextSibling`). Exit this `Do Loop` DOM walk when another `H3` is encountered (with a different `ID`), or there is no sibling element.

Alter your test for `DT/DD` as you will be at the parent `DL` level. When you encounter a `DL` simply access the `DT/DD` by `children(n)`.

I added some initial logic to clear out previous results between runs.

You will need to update code to pick up target value, `targetHazard`, from a cell, and the value of `r` to be the start row number for writing out data.

N.B. Due to older set-ups no longer being supported e.g. Windows 7 set-ups, your mileage with `.NextSibling` may vary due to different handling, within DOM, of text nodes.

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetContents2()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Substance Dossier")   
    r = 2
    
    On Error Resume Next
    ws.Range("B" & r & ":C" & GetLastRow(ws, 2)).ClearContents
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Dim http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    Set http = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60: Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    With http
        .Open "GET", "https://echa.europa.eu/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/15460/7/1", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Dim targetHazard As String, css As String, node As Object, sibling As Object
    
    ''targetHazard would come from sheet
    'targetHazard = "Workers - Hazard for the eyes"
    targetHazard = "Workers - Hazard via inhalation route"
    targetHazard = Replace$(Replace$(Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper("" & targetHazard & ""), Chr$(32), vbNullString), Chr$(45), vbNullString)
    css = Replace$("#SectionContent #s<id>", "<id>", targetHazard)
    
    Set node = html.querySelector(css)
    
    If node Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
 
    With ws
    
        .Cells(2, 2) = node.innerText
    
        Do
        
            Set node = node.NextSibling
        
            If node Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        
            Dim tag As String, header As String, data As String
        
            tag = node.tagName
        
            'Debug.Print tag
        
            If tag = "H3" And node.ID <> targetHazard Then Exit Do
        
            r = r + 1
            
            Select Case tag

            Case "DL"
        
                header = node.Children(0).innerText
                .Cells(r, 2) = header
                data = node.Children(1).innerText
                .Cells(r, 3) = data

            Case Else
        
                header = vbNullString
                .Cells(r, 2) = node.innerText
            
            End Select
        
        Loop
    
    End With
  
End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).row
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Hi again thanks for this. It clearly works but Unfortunately I still run into errors because of how excel processes the nodes. Its strange because it prints the first 6 elements and then I get a runtime error with `header = node.Children(0).innerText` highlighted as the issue.

Comment: You are on a more recent version of Excel aren't you? We can sort this out but will require some discussion. We can discuss [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169987/dawgs-waffle-haus-) if you ping me from there.

Comment: @SIM will probably come across this at some point also and feedback. I believe they have a similar set-up to you. Times like this I wish Microsoft would set-me up with some sort of way to test on different set-ups of their product without me emptying the bank! . Anyone from Microsoft hear me?!!! Sigh.

Comment: will do. Yeah relatively recent. Haha yeah it’s frustrating!